# removing an object from a list while it is being iterated through

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, hashmap

I am currently working on a game and to edit/remove/add all of my entities I have an array List. Every single frame(60x per second) everything in the list is updated, and rendered. When I call for an Object to be added or removed (in the entities update method)I receive an error in "Thread-2". With some quick research I discovered that it is incorrect to edit a list while it is being iterated. Is this the problem I am currently experiencing? or is it because my list isn't "thread safe"?

Render method:

```
public void render(Graphics g){
     for(Entity entity: list){
          entity.render(g);
      }
 }
```

Update method:

```
public void update(){
     for(Entity entity: list){
          entity.update();
      }
 }
```

If my problem is the fact that I am editing a list while it is being updated would this be how to fix it?:

```
public void update(){
     for(Entity entity: list){
          entity.update();
      }

     for(Entity entity: removeList){
          list.remove(entity);
      }
      removeList.clear();
 }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Which line causes it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or is it because my list isn't "thread safe"?

Yes, if `render` and `update` can run at the same time on different threads.

> would this be how to fix it?

No, still the same problem, you'll try to remove while iterating.

Either

1. Build a new list with only the entries you want to keep, and then swap it in as `list` (updating an object reference is atomic), or
2. Synchronize the relevant parts of your `render` and `update` methods on `list`.

Here's an *rough* example of #1:

```
public void update(){

    List newList = new AppropriateListType(list);
    for (Entity entity : removeList){
        newList.remove(entity);
    }
    removeList.clear(); // Or removeList = new AppropriateListType();
    list = newList;

    for (Entity entity: list) {
        entity.update();
    }
}
```

*(Note I reversed the order of those two loops; little point in updating an entity you're about to remove, presumably.)*

That works because nothing can try to iterate the new list while we're modifying it, because until we do `list = newList`, the new list is entirely private to this specific execution of the `update` method. Once we do `list = newList`, it's on the object, so other code will try to use it.

And a *rough* example of #2:

```
public void update(){
    synchronized (list) {
        for (Entity entity: removeList){
            list.remove(entity);
        }
    }
    removeList.clear();

    for (Entity entity: list) {
        // This is probably fine depending on how `render` and `update` work
        // but you *may* need to `synchronize` on `entity` (here and in `render`
        // depending on how `render` and `update` work
        entity.update();
    }
}
```

*(Again with the loops reversed.)*

More about synchronization in [the Java synchronization tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

---

Side note: You may need to check your iteration of and updates to `removeList` as well.

Comment: Crowder If my list is not "threat safe" is there an alternative thread type I can use? How would I go about synchronize the relevant parts of my list?

Comment: @MaxwellBrookes - You'd do the things I described above...?

Comment: is an ArrayList an appropriate list type? or does it have to be a synchronized list?

Comment: @MaxwellBrookes - No need to use one of the lists with synchronization built in if you're doing the things above. So whatever list type is appropriate to what you're doing.